# Smart way to use Collation from Spring Data ReactiveMongoRepository

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

We are developing an Application on Spring 5 Reactive Stack. For persistance we use MongoDb with `ReactiveMongoRepository` (`ReactiveCrudRepository`) from Spring Data.

Currently for fetching data we are using a Query like

```
@Query("{ 'ownerId': ?0, filePath: {$regex: ?1}, tags: { $all : ?2}}")
Flux<Media> findAllByOwnerIdAndFilePathRegexAndTagsContainingAll(String ownerId, String pathRegex, List<Tag> tags);
```

Now we want to get the data by incasesensitive tags. For this I've created a index in the db with a collation like `{ locale: 'en', strength: 2 }` as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/).

Now i want to get my data from db with using the index. The MonogoDB way would be `db.media.find( { filePath: "/example/" } ).collation( { locale: 'en', strength: 2 } )`.

Does someone know a smart way to use Collations from ReactiveMongoRepository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current versions of Spring Data you need to use `MongoOperations` providing a `Query` that defines the `Collation`.
Please refer to the [Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.collation) for details on that.

Please make sure to also check out/comment on [DATAMONGO-1854](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1854) which proposes adding *collation* to `@Query`.